# Localization with EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a I18n application that essentially loads up translations of locale with an ajax call that returns a JSON.

Now, it puts the JSON into Em.STRINGS. In the HTML, I have a handlebar tag that says something like this

> ```
> {{translate context key="LOGOUT_LABEL"}}
> ```

I have written a helper in my JS that looks like this

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('translate', function(property, options) {
    var key = options.hash && options.hash.key, 
    replacants = options.hash && options.hash.values, value;
    if (key) {
        value = Em.String.loc(key, replacants ? Em.String.w(replacants) : []); 
        return value ;
    }
});
```

When this runs, my HTML gets painted first and the AJAX call happens next. So, the translations effectively don't show up!. How do I fix this?

Here's the fiddle URL : http://jsfiddle.net/infinityat0/gBa7T/

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work:

```
var App = Em.Application.create({
    locale: 'en_US',
    init: function () {
        var locale = this.get('locale') || 'en_US';
        $.get("http://localhost:8000/translations.json", {
            locale: locale
        }, function (data) {
            Ember.STRINGS = data;
        });
    }
});
```

Actually your fiddle works, if you replace the AJAX-Call. An Ajax-Call to localhost can't work in a fiddle. See a working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/gBa7T/1/).

**UPDATE:**
If you want to write an own helper for this usecase, you would have to create a bound helper. This is available in the latest ember release ([ember doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper)). Your code could look like this:

```
Em.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('translate', function (property, options) {
    var key = options.hash && options.hash.key,
        replacants = options.hash && options.hash.values,
        value;
    if (key) {
        value = Em.String.loc(key, replacants ? Em.String.w(replacants) : []);
        console.log(value);
        console.log(Ember.STRINGS);
        return value;
    }
}, "Ember.STRINGS");
```

**NOTE:**
There is a project called [ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n). You should probably build upon that instead of working on such a low level api.

Comment: Hey, @mavilein Thanks a lot for your reply. I know that the AJAX call wont work in JSFiddle (I just kept it for clarity sake). Also, that, if i just keep the json string in the html it will work (because it essentially means I have pre-fetched the translations and applied during init.  What I actually wanted was to fetch the translations in an AJAX call, assign the JSON to Em.Strings and then after this is done, the handlebars update themselves because there's change in Em.STRINGS.

Comment: Why don't you use ember-i18n. It takes care of this kind of issues.